# usage of memcpy()

Tags: c, memcpy

Since two days I am playing with C and I come across new problem all the time. Right now I want to do memcopy my data into a char buf, but I am encountering some problems: My code is below:

```
         int main(int argc, char *argv[])
        {
         int sockfd, portno, n;
         struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
         struct hostent *server;
     unsigned char buf[1024];

        struct profile_t 
      {
        unsigned char length;
        unsigned char type;
        unsigned char *data;
      };

        typedef struct profile_datagram_t
      {
        unsigned char src[4];
        unsigned char dst[4];
        unsigned char ver;
        unsigned char n;
        struct profile_t profiles[MAXPROFILES];     
      } header;


      header outObj;

      outObj.src[0] =1;
  outObj.dst[0] = 2;
  outObj.ver = 1;
  outObj.n = 2;


  outObj.profiles[0].length = 10;
  outObj.profiles[0].type = 1;
  outObj.profiles[1].length = 10;
  outObj.profiles[1].type = 2;




  memcpy(buf,outObj.src,4);
  memcpy(buf+4,outObj.dst,4);
  memcpy(buf+8,outObj.ver,1);
  memcpy(buf+9,outObj.n,2);


  memcpy(buf+10,outObj.profiles[0].length,1);
  memcpy(buf+11,outObj.profiles[0].type,1);
  memcpy(buf=12,outObj.profiles[0].data,10);
```

I am getting the following errors:

> warning: passing argument 2 of `memcpy` makes pointer from integer without a cast
>   error: incompatible types when assigning to type `unsigned char[1024]` from type `int`

The errors are for `memcpy()`. Can anyone explain me about `memcpy()` and also where I am going wrong.

Comment: Unrelated: `buf=12` in the last line will compile but do very wrong things...

Comment: @sth: really? I believe that's where his incompatible types error is coming from. Now if `buf` was a pointer...

Comment: @sixlettervariables `buf=12` is used as the destination for `memcpy`.  That means that it is going to try to write to address `12`.

Comment: @six: You are of course right there, and even if `buf` were a pointer you should get a warning.

Comment: @David, not if `buf` is `unsigned char[1024]`...hence the second error he received.

Comment: @sixlettervariables, good catch. I didn't notice that `buf` was an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the address of the various fields of your structures. When you pass an array by name, that is automatically the address of the beginning of the array. But the non-array fields need the address-of operator `&`:

```
memcpy(buf+10,&outObj.profiles[0].length,1);
```

As an aside, this is better in case you change the type of `length`:

```
memcpy(buf+10,&outObj.profiles[0].length,sizeof(outObj.profiles[0].length));
```

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! If I could up vote twice I would.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems that I'll touch on:

- You'll need to use the address of the non-pointer items in the structures like `ver` or `n`:

  ```
  /* note the & before outObj.ver */
  memcpy(buf+8, &outObj.ver, 1);
  ```
- You accidentally assign a value to `buf` in the last line:

  ```
  memcpy(buf=12,... /* should be buf+12 */
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a tip, if you are *sure* about the memory layout and endianess of your `buf`, and the struct (including its padding, and alignment) you could simply do a cast like:

```
header * outObj = (header *)buf;
```

And automagically access the members. Like `header->ver`, `header->src`, etc